# cumulative sum pandas dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

I would like a cumulative sum with some conditions, the regular cumulative sum is given by column b, however I would like the cumulative sum result in column d which does sth a normal cum sum does not: Firstly, regular operation of cumulative sum when the result of the sum is within bounds (given by `0.2` and `0.4`). However, When column d has exceeded a lower boundary (`0.2`) or upper boundary (`0.4`) I would like it to add a specific value when column a is zero (respectively `0.1` and `-0.1`). Desired additions and subtractions are given in column c. Row 4 and 7 are the modified rows, other rows are regular cumsum operations.

```
       a     b    c      d 
  1  0.1   0.1    0.1    0.1
  2  0.2   0.3    0.2    0.3
  3 -0.11  0.19  -0.11   0.19
  4  0.0   0.19   0.1    0.29
  5 -0.07  0.12  -0.07   0.22
  6  0.2   0.32   0.2    0.42
  7  0.0   0.32  -0.1    0.32
```

Comment: What code are you currently using to generate what you have now?

Comment: df['b']= df['a'].cumsum(), column c and d are desired output

Comment: When should it be 0.1 and when -0.1? Every second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value to add actually depends on the current sum. IMHO this will be hard to express with true pandas expression, so I would just try to iterate on the underlying numpy arrays:

```
a = df['a'].values
d = np.zeros(len(a))
old = 0.
nv = 0.1
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != 0. or (.2 < old < .4):
        d[i] = old + a[i]
    else:
        d[i] = old + nv
        nv = -nv
    old = d[i]

df['d'] = d
```

It gives as expected:

```
      a     d
0  0.10  0.10
1  0.20  0.30
2 -0.11  0.19
3  0.00  0.29
4 -0.07  0.22
5  0.20  0.42
6  0.00  0.32
```

Not as efficient as a true vectorized operation, but still much more efficient that a `iterrows`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in steps (not sure this will be any faster than [Serge's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56293603/3284713).

We have your column `df['a']` and start by creating a column `df['b']` as the cumsum and a column `df['c']` as a copy of `df['a']` (this can be avoided if you don't mind modifying values on `df['a']`.

```
       a     b      c     
  1  0.1    0.1    0.1  
  2  0.2    0.3    0.2   
  3  -0.11  0.19   -0.11  
  4  0.0    0.19   0.0  
  5  -0.07  0.12   -0.07   
  6  0.2    0.32   0.2   
  7  0.0    0.32   0.0
```

We can now modify the values in `df['c']` following the required conditions:

```
df.loc[(df['a']==0) & (df['b']<0.2),'c']=0.1
df.loc[(df['a']==0) & (df['b']>0.4),'c']=-0.1
```

and finally take the cumsum of `df['c']`

```
df['c'].cumsum()

Out[]: 
1    0.10
2    0.30
3    0.19
4    0.29
5    0.22
6    0.42
7    0.42
```